# WCF calls CrossCallContamination (that's a thing right?)

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a huuuuge problem. While developing a solution for a customer i never had a problem with this but after deploying the solution in their environment more and more issues are surfacing.

**Setup**

 We have an (wpf) application that gets served some basic html markup and gets rendered (through Essential Objects). This is called through a (now) PERCALL setup of WCF.

**Problem**

 Sometimes the call of user1 gets mixed up and gets served to user2. This happens more frequent as more users connects and uses the program. Since the data is used in day-to-day operations this is viewed as **bad**.

**Bad solution**
We've implemented a solution that, should work but the problem needs to be fixed anyway. We call each service three times and compares the results in order to ensure that the majority of responses are correct. Since the problem happens without any sort of pattern other than when many users are connected.

**Better solution**
I've been looking over WEBAPI/2 for a potential replacement structure for handling our calls, however we send large amounts of data and objects that, put simply, would require *some* reconstruction on both the server and client, and time is of the essence at this junction.

Googling has yielded few, if any, results on this. What am I missing?

Comment: "this is viewed as bad" ... quite rightly. It is a serious bug in your service.

Comment: @Clemens correct.

Comment: As @Clemens said, this is not only *"viewed as bad"*, but moreover critically for your users privacy. It severly **violates their privacy** when their requests get mixed up and they recieve responses that were meant for someone else. Apart from that, doing 3 calls and comparing them when only one would be needed is a very, very costly operation. If I were you, I would urgently revise the infrastructure of the service.

Comment: Did you try `PerSession` instead of `PerCall`? And make sure you protect shared resources (e.g. database) against concurrent access.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Well.. Yes. The perverbial shit has hit the fan. However. This only happens once every 500 calls or so. It makes it EXTREMLY difficult to track down.

Comment: @Clemens I went with PerCall in order to circumvent the issue of having shared states etc. PerCall should instantiate a new object each time, which, to me, should totally eliminate this issue. However.. Well.. It doesn't..

Comment: I use several `wcf`services and I never seen a issue like that, I think this can be a bug in your code, using some shared resouce or anything like that...such a critical bug, in own `wcf` probably would be already resolved.. could you share your code?